# Cannot run compiled go files

Tags: linux, executable

I just tried installing Go following the official doc: https://golang.org/doc/install#install

However, I encountered a problem when I tested the installation.

I created the `hello.go` file like the example in the doc. 
I can `go build hello.go` successfully, but I cannot run the compiled binary file.
Moreover, I can `go run hello.go`.

```
heyuan@pop-os:~/Other/temp$ cat hello.go 
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
heyuan@pop-os:~/Other/temp$ go build hello.go 
heyuan@pop-os:~/Other/temp$ ls
hello  hello.go
heyuan@pop-os:~/Other/temp$ hello

Command 'hello' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install hello              # version 2.10, or
sudo apt  install hello            
sudo apt  install hello-traditional

See 'snap info hello' for additional versions.

heyuan@pop-os:~/Other/temp$ go run hello.go 
hello, world
```

Here are my environment variables

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/home/heyuan/Software/go
export PATH=${GOROOT}/bin:${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin
```

Comment: Type `./hello` instead of just `hello`. Running an executable binary is not Go related.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just followed the doc and did not realize the example is in a Windows environment.

Comment: The documentation you've linked to even says: "Execute it to see the greeting:

`$ ./hello`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` you can run the executable putting `./` before the file.

In your case you have to do:

```sh
./hello
```

If the executable is in another folder, than you need to specify the path:

```sh
/opt/SP/executable/hello
```